# MongoDB 3.2 - how to pass password from command line?

Tags: mongodb

I have a question that seems trivial. But it is not, at least not to me.

I want to be able to login to a password-protected MongoDB (v3.2) instance withouth having to type in password manually (I want to pass it in connection string from console). It seems that it should go like this:

```
hostnamename:port/database -u someUser -p 'password'
```

But it does not work as expected :( So let's take a loot at three scenarios.

(1) Connect with password prompt - when I type the password it works as expected, I can login. Here is console output and logs:

```
# hostnamename:27017/admin -u root -p
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
Enter password:
connecting to: hostname:27017/admin
>

I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from ip:port #232 (11 connections now open)
I ACCESS   [conn232] Successfully authenticated as principal root on admin
I NETWORK  [conn232] end connection ip:port (10 connections now open)
```

(2) Try to connect with password already passed. I still get asked for password. If I don't type it in the console just keeps waiting.

```
# hostnamename:27017/admin -u root -p 'password'
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
Enter password:

(no logs are generated until password is typed)
```

(3) Try to connect with password already passed. I still get asked for password. I type it in... and some weird stuff happens. Connection crashes with 'password' value (then one passed in connection string), but logs say that the user was connected.

```
# hostnamename:27017/admin -u root -p 'something'
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
Enter password:
connecting to: hostname:27017/admin
E -        [main] file [something] doesn't exist
failed to load: something


I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from ip:port #233 (11 connections now open)
I ACCESS   [conn233] Successfully authenticated as principal root on admin
I NETWORK  [conn233] end connection ip:port (10 connections now open)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also I'd like to add that if there was something similat to PostgreSQL's env variable ("export PGPASSWORD") that would also work for me.

Comment: Just tested. For MongoDB 2.4 it works without any issues `mongo hostname/database -u username -p password`. So the issue is related to MongoDB version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported it to the guys from Mongo: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32421, it's confirmed as a bug.

Meanwhile, the workaround is to not leave space between -p flag and password:

```
mongo hostname:port/database -u username -pPassword
```

Comment: This must have been modeled after [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password). And if you put your mind to it, it makes sense to demand no space between `-p` and password if the latter can be omitted (`-p` without password to enter manually). Or else, how can it tell whether the next argument is a password or e.g. a database name?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a .mongorc.js file with your connection info in your directory. You just then type mongo with your options. Here is an example:

```
db = connect("server:27017/admin");
db.auth('user','password');
```

Comment: The connection is successful, but it also gets closed within a second. Also I am not happy with having to create another file just to authenticate. Seems like that will not be good for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try : [username:password@]host1[:port1] ??

for example `root:password@hostnamename:27017`

[official documentation connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Comment: I'd like to emphasise I'm connecting from Debian's shell via mongo client. As far as I know these strings are of no use here. Am I wrong?

Comment: For me it worked to pass the user with `-u` and no space but no password at all- it then prompted for the password (assuming you're able to run this interactively)

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering password with quotes, please enter without quotes.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/program/mongo/#options

Comment: No effect here. I still get asked for password, type it in, press enter and there's an error `# mongo hostname:27017/admin -u root -p password
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
Enter password:
connecting to: hostname:27017/admin

E -        [main] file [password] doesn't exist
failed to load: password`